# Skip logic if no file when adding a PDF to a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA code in Excel.

```
Sub Collect_PDFs()
    
    Dim i As Integer
    
    i = 1
    Do Until Cells(i, 4) = ""
    On Error GoTo Error:
    Workbooks("Agilent Data Importer.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(i * 4, 10).Select
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:= _
        Sheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 4) _
        , Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
        Range("G1"), _
        IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:=Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)).Select
Error:
    i = i + 1
    Loop
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 2")).Select
    Selection.Delete
    Workbooks("Agilent Data Importer.xlsm").Activate
    Columns("A:I").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Rows("1:3").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "PDFs"
    Sheets("PDFs").Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

If the file is not present I get this error message.
[image: Error message]

I would like to skip the iteration if the file isn't present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Dir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function) to check if the file actually exists, like the following (untested as of posting):

```vb
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("Agilent Data Importer.xlsm")

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

Dim iconFile As String
iconFile = ws.Range("G1").Value

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 to lastRow

    Dim myFileName As String
    myFileName = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value

    Dim label As String
    label = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value

    Dim destCell As Range
    Set destCell = ws.Cells(i * 4, 10)

    If Dir(fileName) <> "" Then
        ws.OLEObjects.Add _
            FileName:=myFileName, Link:=False, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:=iconFile, _
            IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:=label, _
            Left:=destCell.Left, Top:=destCell.Top
    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the filesystemobject to check whether the file exists or not. something like this. Instead of this error block, I would use an if then else statement.

```
Sub CollectPdfs()

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set objSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' Get last row
    intLastRow = objSheet.UsedRange.Rows(objSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    
    For i = 1 To intLastRow
        strFilename = objSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value
        If fso.FileExists(strFilename) Then
            ...
        Else
            ...
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```